# How to correctly insert a $variable in a pdo foreach result?

Tags: php, foreach, pdo

I'm still relatively new to PHP but wants to code "the right way". Actually, i have this :

```
function listCategories()
{
    $stmt = DB::run("SELECT * FROM categories");
    foreach ($stmt as $row)
    {
        echo "<li><a href='index.php?cat=". $row['id'] .">". $row['catname'] ."</a></li>";
    }
}
```

i need to add the $variable "$language" in each ". $row['catname'] ." with a underscore before "$language" like ". $row['catname"underscore"$language'] ." what is the best practice to achieve this ?

Comment: `. $row['catname_' . $language] .`  ???

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this instead:

```
echo "<li><a href='index.php?cat=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['catname'] . "_$language</a></li>";
```